# Assigning a string reference to a pointer

Tags: c++11, pointers

I've been stuck on this one problem all day and maybe someone can explain it to me? I'm not providing my exact code, but a similar situation of what I'm trying to accompish (and the shortened version). It's a restaurant simulator.

```
int main() {
    Restaurant i;
    string tableID;
    cin >> tableID;
    i.append(new Table(tableID));//this appends a new table to the linked list
}
//.h file we're not allowed to modify
class Table
{
public:
    Table(const string& tableID);//constructor
private:
    string* tableID;
}
// .cpp file I'm writing
Table::Table(const string& tableID){
    this->tableID = tableID;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> table.cc:9:18: error: cannot convert ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string*}’ in assignment
>       this->tableID = tableID;

Can anyone tell me what's going on? To me it seems like it's passing the address of `tableID` in `main()` and assigning it to a pointer in the constructor, which I thought was legal but maybe it's the `const` throwing me off.

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty clear. You are trying to assign an expression of type `string` to a variable of type "pointer to `string`". It doesn't work for the same reason `int* p = 42;` wouldn't work - neither makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was it, but i couldn't figure out how I'm gonna convert that string to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

1. Change the definition of `tableID` in class `Table` to be `string tableID`. In this case you'll keep a copy of the value in the instance.
2. Change the assignment to `this->tableID` to be `this->tableID = &tableID`. In this case you'll assign the address of the `tableID` parameter to `this->tableID`. In this case you'll only keep a pointer to the table name in the instance, which could cause some interesting behavior. You'll probably learn the most with this approach.
3. Change the assignment to `this->tableId = new string(tableID)`. Here you're allocating a new `string`, populating it with the value of the parameter `tableID`, and then assigning the address of the new string to the instance var `tableID`. But because you don't have a destructor defined for this class you'll leak this allocated string every time you destroy an instance to `Table`.

Perhaps some combination of the above would be best.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! Here's what I came up.

Comment: A side note: Use `this->tableID = new(std::nothrow) std::string(tableID);` cause you you don't want to (possibly) throw exception in constructor.

Comment: 1. I can't change the definition because the.h file was given to us and it won't compile online if we change that. 2. That was first thought, but I get a slightly different error. converting from const to basic string. 3. That one actually worked. There is a destructor in the.h file, so i should just need to create the destructor in the class implementaion and I'm good. Thank you!